# Simple log in with Facebook C# SDK not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I'm new to the Facebook apps and recently read the doc available. Then, I proceeded to get the Facebook C# SDK from NuGet and read the [get started tutorial](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started).

I modified it a little. I have 3 pages:

- Default.aspx : has the "log in with facebook" button
- Protected.aspx : the page that I ultimately want to be unaccessible without first logging in
- DoSignIn.aspx : contains the request for the token and redirects back to Default.aspx
- On the Default.aspx, I have a button that redirects me to the Protected.aspx page. On it, I have a label showing me the token.

Now, my issue is this:

- When I click on the "log in with facebook" button, the button doesn't change to show that I'm logged in. It only shows that I'm logged in if I do a refresh on the page.
- If I click on the button to redirect me to the Protected.aspx page, I can't see the token in the Label because the DoSignIn.aspx page was never called.

If someone could point me in what I do wrong (as I nearly copied the tutorial example), I would be very grateful. I spent the past 3 hours fiddling with this and searching Google and SO all over and don't know where to search anymore.

Thank you for your time.

PS. I have the latest Facebook C# SDK and the App ID seems to work fine as when I manually refresh my browser, I am indeed logged in.

I add the code for the 3 pages:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'I_INSERTED_MY_APP_ID_HERE', // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });


            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    // - Handle the access token -
                    // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                    // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                    form.setAttribute("action", 'DoSignIn.aspx');

                    var field = document.createElement("input");
                    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                    field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                    form.appendChild(field);

                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                }
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1">
            Log in with Facebook</div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Go to protected" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Protected.aspx");
    }
}
```

**DoSignIn.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class DoSignIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accessToken = Request["accessToken"];
        Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Protected.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class Protected : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["AccessToken"] != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            Label1.Text = "Not authenticated";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors when you load the Default page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I have spent hours searching and finally found why it is not working. It has nothing to do with the code above but with a Facebook bug. Actually, it seems that many people can't have the auth.authResponseChange to fire as the session refreshes. I found several bugs reports on FB describing the complete issue, one of them being [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/351374538207243?browse=search_4f4ee2d8a15cb1913026038).

This issue I had when developing on /localhost/. I had already moved to a different way to integrate Facebook Login when, before deleting the above samples, I tried uploading it on an actual hosting server under a domain name. For a reason I can't explain, it just works from there.

Anyway, the implementation for the Facebook login I'm currently pursuing is explained [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-integrate-facebook-login.html).